# Vue 3: keep custom element with upper case after Vue compilation

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

## What is happening?

I have a custom tag like this:

```
<h:inputText id="j_username" class="form-control"/>
```

When I execute npm run build the tag is changed to this:

```
<h:inputtext id="j_username" class="form-control"/>
```

Note here: in 'h:commandLink' the upper case 'L' was changed to lower case 'l'! Now, the framework I use cannot render it anymore unfortunately.

## Why do I want this behaviour?

The framework I use needs this specific tag. I use it on a page to do a security login mechanism. I only have one page in my Vue app like this, but I need it. There is no other solution for me. I tried replacing the tag with other ones, but no luck. So I am stuck to h:inputText with capital 'T'.

So bottom line, the page is created with Vue components, like navigation and headers and stuff like that. When it is then deployed to the server, and a request is done for that specific page it gets parsed by my framework to be able to do some specific security stuff...

## What do I want?

I would like to find a way where after npm run build is executed, the custom element retains whatsoever it's original camel casing.

## What did I already tried?

In my entrypoint:

```
const app = Vue.createApp({...})
app.config.isCustomElement = tag => tag.startsWith('h:')
```

Tried to work with all possible html-webpack options (// https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin) and minify options (https://github.com/kangax/html-minifier), without luck.

Also tried to add directives to the tag, or wrap it like following examples

```
<div v-pre id="username">
    <h:inputText id="j_username" class="form-control"/>
</div>
```

Or:

```
<div v-html="inputElement" id="username"></div>
... created() { ...  inputElement: '<h:inputText id="j_username" class="form-control"/>' ... }
```

Comment: Vue uses VDOM, wich means it will create a DOM element for all tags in the template. DOM doesn't support tags camelcased. I would solve this using kebab case first and after Vue processed the template convert kebab to camel.

Comment: @lmarqs `DOM doesn't support tags camelcased` - Do you have any source to back that up? According to WC3, [tag names are case-insensitive](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/syntax.html) and may be written with any mix of lower- and uppercase letters. And how do you "convert kebab to camel" after Vue has processed the template, would you care to elaborate more on that please?

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid we can't change the way tag names are specified because it's part of [the specs](https://dev.w3.org/html5/html-author/#html-and-xhtml-comparison-0) with HTML, just like how self-closing tags are not supported (in the final output), except for void elements and foreign content elements. Also taking into account that [Vue templates need to be a valid HTML](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/1036#issuecomment-120634281).

As for the `isCustomElement` config, that won't probably do much here either, other than preventing Vue from throwing a warning about an "unknown custom element" (during development), because it's simply a method to recognize custom elements defined outside of Vue (e.g. using the Web Components APIs).

Considering the extent of your template-specific requirements, it's probably the right time to look into [Vue SSR](https://ssr.vuejs.org/) where you get to decide on the final output (fully rendered page).